# Why is this validation rule not working?

Tags: validation-rule

I have tried this with another ID, which is a queue and it works as expected, but it does not work when I use a User. Any input is helpful, Thanks

```
AND(
    $Profile.Name <> "System Administrator",
    $Profile.Name <> "Marketing Administrator",
    $Profile.Name <> "Eloqua",
    PRIORVALUE(OwnerId) = "0053n000007aufaAAA",
    ISCHANGED(OwnerId)
)
```

Comment: Why to hardcode the OwnerId check? How will this work in other orgs as id will be different there? And most importantly you have give 15 digit id intead od 18 digit. Can you remove last three digit from id and try?

Comment: Thank you! I also found the reason, which was the 15 vs 18 digit. In validation rules, only 15 digit IDs work.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [Custom Permission](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.custom_perms_overview.htm&type=5), and as describe in this [Knowledge Article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000332129&mode=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&type=1):

```
AND(NOT($Permission.CAN_CHANGE_OWNER), ISCHANGED(OwnerId))
```

Then, create a Permission Set, assign the Custom Permission to it, and then assign that Permission Set to users that should be allowed to change the ownership.

Comment: If the condition is based on the owner then this approach would not work though.

Comment: Thank you! I found the reason, which was the 15 vs 18 digit. In validation rules, only 15 digit IDs work.